# I have a bitcoin address , how do I check how much bit coin I have

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core

How can I check my bitcoin address. I have the address but how do I access it

Comment: your question is a bit short, and cannot be answered. Maybe you want to outline a bit more, which OS you use, what application you use, what you see, or where you're looking at?

Answer (score 1):

[**Blockchain.info**](https://www.blockchain.info) and enter the **address** into the search field. Your wallet controls the private key associated with the public address used to receive funds.  Control of private keys enable funds to be spent by your wallet.